# samy Query display different rows in different server

Tags: mysql, mariadb

executing same query in different server (both server are having same records)
please check query below

```
SELECT  id,NAME,parent_id 
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM projects
ORDER BY parent_id) AS res,
(SELECT @pv := '944')AS res_b
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(parent_id, @pv)
AND     @pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', id)
```

Result in my local

**return 45 rows**

Result in my server

**return 42 rows**

in my local using innoDB but in server mariaDB.please help me to slove this issue.

Comment: "local using innoDB but in server mariaDB" These are not equivalent. innoDB is a table type, mariaDB is a DB server engine. Can you clarify please?

Comment: I must admit that MySQL variables in queries often confuse me; I never know when they are set. But I see one thing though that may account for the difference: In `SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY parent_id` you order by parent_id, but this is superfluous, because tables and derived tables have no inherent order. This means: your `ORDER BY` clause may be completely ignored by the DBMS. So if your variable logic builds up on this order, it may fail.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery returns an unordered set of rows, *in spite of the `ORDER BY`*.  That's the standard.

You can *perhaps* trick it by adding `LIMIT 99999999` after the `ORDER BY parent_id`.